# Concepts and Design of PluginController

Tags: c++

I ran across a cute plugin controller on this site TinyURL.com/ns42lv and would like to find out where I can learn more about the concept/design of a plug in controller. I use Windows as my OS and do most of my programming in C++.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.ddj.com/cpp/204202899?cid=RSSfeed_DDJ_Cpp) a great article on how to write a plugin management system for portable C/C++.